# Do chromium browsers leave any cue that they have been closed?

Tags: x11

I have been working on a small window manager project. Currently, I am running into an issue with closing browsers by exiting the last open tab. In theory everything should close, however the internal browser window closes and the frame is left up. I can simply destroy the frame, but to do that I need to know when the browser has closed.

Upon closing, the browser sends an unmap request. Problem is `event.event` in the unmap request is the root window. Before I do anything I make sure I am not messing around with the root window. For this I have a simple check:

```
if(event.event == ROOT)
{
    return;
}
```

By removing this before unframing windows I cause other problems. So I need to know if there is a standard way to know when to unframe a window after a browser has been closed by exiting the last remaining tab.

Comment: the browser may have a setting to disable that behavior

Comment: @jsotola I dont think so.. For now I am using Brave and other window managers will close everything properly without me having to adjust anything.